# Как сделать задачу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите функцию interval_intersect(a, b, c, d), которая принимает четыре параметра и возвращает True, если отрезки [a, b] и [c, d] пересекаются, и False иначе. Вы можете предполагать, что a <= b, c <= d

Замечание: вернуть необходимо логические константы True или False, а не строки "True" или "False"

Sample Input:
1 10 5 9

Sample Output:
True

```
def interval_intersect(a, b, c, d):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][1] - line1[1][1], line2[0][1] - line2[1][1]) 

    def interval_intersect(a, b, c, d):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
       raise Exception('lines do not intersect')

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    return x, y

print(line_intersection((A, B), (C, D)))
```

Comment: Критерий пересечения двух интервалов прост как [censored]: любое начало меньше другого кончала. Т.е. `return a<d && c<b`. Если касание считается пересечением - сделать неравенства нестрогими.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def interval_intersect(a, b, c, d):
    return bool(set(range(a, b + 1)) & set(range(c, d + 1)))
```

*Объяснение:*

`set(range(a, b + 1))` и `set(range(c, d + 1))` создают множества с элементами от a до b и от c до d включительно.

(То есть для входных данных 1, 3, 2, 4 это будет {1, 2, 3} и {2, 3, 4})

В `range` ко второму аргументу прибавляем единицу, так как в `range` не входит значение второго аргумента, а только число перед ним.

Оператор `&` возвращает пересечение множеств, то есть элементы, находящиеся в обоих множествах одновременно.

Так как нам надо, чтобы функция возвращала `True` или `False`, то добавляем `bool()`.

Данная функция вернет `True` во всех случаях, когда пересечением не является пустое множество - что нам и надо.

Comment: Извините, не подскажите, как из данного решения вывести True если они пересекаются и False, если не пересекаются, а то для меня это сложно)

Comment: @Deus добавил объяснение

Answer (score 2):

поскольку  *Вы можете предполагать, что a <= b, c <= d* достаточно сравнить максимум левых концов отрезков с минимумом правых

```
def interval_intersect(a, b, c, d):
    return max(a,c) < min(b,d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def interval_intersect(a, b, c, d):
    return (a <= c <= b <= d) | (c <= a <= d <= b) | (a <= c <= d <= b) | (c <= a <= b <= d)
```